# How early in a year can one report tax in U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Each year, I am almost always behind in reporting my tax. Besides I am often busy and may be forgetful, there are other reasons:

- Firstly I am not sure when W-2 forms, 1099 forms, ..., and other tax forms should be ready required by law.
- Secondly, some providers of the tax forms  may revise the forms later, for example, some brokerage company.

So I would give a long wait before I start to report my tax.
I wonder if not considering personal reasons, how early one can  collect all their tax information/forms from their providers, and report their taxes? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly I am not sure when W-2 forms, 1099 forms, ..., and other tax
>   forms should be ready required by law.

W2 should be furnished by January 31st. Same goes to 1099-INT and 1099-MISC. 1099-B and 1099-DIV are usually available in mid-February, but are likely to be amended by the end of March in various common cases (qualified dividends calculation being the most common). K-1 can be as late as May, and if the S-Corp/partnership is not on top of it - even later.

> Secondly, some tax forms providers may revise the forms later, for
>   example, some brokerage company.

As I said - some corrections are expected and if you think you're in the class of investors that is expecting corrections - you should probably wait till late March.

If you only have very simple tax situation (for example, if you're qualified to file 1040EZ) - you're likely to be able to do it as soon as IRS starts accepting returns, which is usually beginning of February. For more complicated situations - you are probably going to wait some time.

You can always get an automatic extension by filing [form 4868](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-4868,-Application-for-Automatic-Extension-of-Time-To-File-U.S.-Individual-Income-Tax-Return).

Comment: Thanks. why are there corrections? Can those providers be more responsible to do their calculation, instead of pushing the tax reporter very late into the deadline?

Comment: Btw, the deadline is always in the busiest time of the spring semester for a student.

Comment: @Tim well, I'm as annoyed as you're about this, but that's the situation. It appears that calculating qualified dividends (there are some holding requirements that go into the future from the payment) requires some delay.

Comment: Do you happen to know why IRS set the deadline to be April 15th, instead of a later date or some more flexible way?

Comment: @Tim because that's the law. IRS can only postpone the deadline if 15th falls on a weekend or a holiday. But the extension using form 4868 is automatic, and should be enough for everyone.

Comment: Congress made the deadline April 15th to give more time for all this recordkeeping and to delay cutting refund checks so early, according to [this writer](http://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/fortune_archive/2002/04/15/321414/index.htm).  Of course, that only sort of makes sense, since today the IRS is disbursing huge sums of EITC and other refunds in February and March, rather than waiting until the end of May.  But the recordkeeping rationale certainly makes sense, so that people can collect their forms and preparers can have more time to handle all the work.